# Attachments fail with error 500 with KiwiTCMS 10.0

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I just installed on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu, the 10.0 version of KiwiTCMS  based on the docker image as explained here : https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing_docker.html.

It seems to work pretty well as I can create a test plan, test cases and test executions.

The issue comes when I try to attach some screenshots to my test execution, I can select a file on my disk but then it fails with an error 500.
I checked that the uploads volume is well mounted.

Do you have some idea about what I forgot to configure?

Comment: Without error logs there's nothing we can do to help you, see https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html#troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

I've solved exactly same problem giving write permisstions to "uploads" folder.
In my case,

`chmod ugoa+rwx /opt/kiwi_tcms/uploads`

ER